# Postgres возвращает странную ошибку при изменении столбца

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE study_contents
(
  id            SERIAL             NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT study_contents_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY,
  content       VARCHAR(512)       NOT NULL,
  transcription VARCHAR(512),
  image_id      INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT study_contents_image_id_foreign
    REFERENCES files,
  sound_id      INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT study_contents_sound_id_foreign
    REFERENCES files,
  deleted_at    TIMESTAMP(0),
  type          STUDY_CONTENT_TYPE NOT NULL
);
```

В которой нужно изменить тип полей `content` и `transcription` на `TEXT`. При выполнении любого из запросов:

```
ALTER TABLE study_contents ALTER COLUMN content TYPE TEXT;
ALTER TABLE study_contents ALTER COLUMN transcription TYPE TEXT, 
                           ALTER COLUMN transcription SET NOT NULL;
```

выводится ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "type" of relation "study_contents" does not exist (SQL: alter table "study_contents" drop column "type")
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "type" of relation "study_contents" does not exist
```

Как я понимаю - проблема в поле type, но почему оно мешает изменить тип у других полей?

Возможно проблема в перечислении `STUDY_CONTENT_TYPE` ? Оно выглядит так:

```
CREATE TYPE STUDY_CONTENT_TYPE AS ENUM ('phrase', 'text', 'word');
```

Comment: Мне в сообщении об ошибке текст в скобках не нравится, он же вроде приводит там выполняемый запрос и там почему то drop column. в чем вы выполняете эти запросы, это средство не может делать что то от себя ?

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Вы правы. Там другая миграция мешала